# Delete repeated array in multil-dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have one multi-dimensional array of categories and subcategories, but one subcategory (in [childs]) can't be parent, i need to delete parent category that is subcategory to.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => Homilías
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [name] => Obituario
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [name] => ACTUALIDAD
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Homilías
                            [id] => 6
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                       (
                            [id] => 11
                            [name] => Obituario
                       )
                 )
         )
)
```

Comment: you mean delete the `childs` or `2`???

Comment: Thanks for quick answer Frayne, i need to delete first two categories, because they are child of "Actualidad", and the can't be parent because that :)

Comment: simply use `unset($arr[0])` and `unset($arr[1])`

Comment: ok, but in this case, how can i know that this sub-category is not in parent? i tried with in_array, but it seems to not working

Comment: you can check that is in any subcategory or not. if then remove the parent.

Comment: Ok, use 'array_unique' function in loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_walk_recursive, like this..

```
<?php
$array = array(
  0 => array(
      'id' => 6,
      'name' => 'Homilias'
  ),
  1 => array(
      'id' => 11,
      'name' => 'Obituario'
  ),
  2 => array(
      'id' => 12,
      'name' => 'ACTUALIDAD',
      'childs' => array(
          0 => array(
              'name' => 'Homilias',
              'id' => 6
          ),
          1 => array (
              'id' => 11,
              'name' => 'Obituario'
          )
      )
  )
);

$rootCategories = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if(!isset($value['childs']))
        $rootCategories[$key] = $value['name'];
}

array_walk_recursive($array, 'MyClass::removeDuplicatedRoot', array($rootCategories, &$array));

class MyClass
{
    static function removeDuplicatedRoot($myArray, $key, $data)
    {
        $keyToRemove = array_search($myArray, $data[0]);
        if ($key == 'name' && false !== $keyToRemove) {
            unset($data[1][$keyToRemove]);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($array);
```